# Rails Search 3.2 Returns all instead of specific Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, rails-activerecord

I have a simple search method installed in my Rails app that I want to be called from ajax, in another controller view.

Right now one looks like so:

```
class CensusController < ApplicationController

def search
  @census = Census.where("'NBRHD_NAME' like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")

  render :json => @census.to_json
end

end
```

And in my other View/Controller

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
        var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
        var offset = kmlEvent.latLng;
        showInInfoWindow(text, offset);
        map.panTo(kmlEvent.latLng);
        map.setZoom(13);
        //console.log(kmlEvent);
        showInContentDiv(text);
    });

    function showInInfoWindow(text, offset) {
        var content = "<div>" + text + "</div>";
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content,
            position: offset
        });
        infoWindow.open(map);

    }

    function showInContentDiv(neighborName) {
        var query = neighborName;
        var url = "census/search?query=" + query;

        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            console.log(url);

            var neigh = data;

            for (var i in neigh.object)
            {
                console.log(neigh);
            }
        });
```

I just want the neighborhood name returned and matched to the one in my database, instead all Database names are returned in the JSON format.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Again I am running Rails 3.2 with MySQL2 gem

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses single quotes for string literals so this query:

```
@census = Census.where("'NBRHD_NAME' like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

is really asking for all rows where the string literal `'NBRHD_NAME'` contains `params[:search]`. Presumably you want to look at the *column* `NBRHD_NAME` rather than the *string* `'NBRHD_NAME'` so you should say:

```
@census = Census.where("`NBRHD_NAME` like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

or

```
@census = Census.where("NBRHD_NAME like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

AFAIK, MySQL's case sensitivity for columns depends on the configuration so you should use the backticked version to be safe if you're working with column names that really were created in upper case. Note that backtick-quoting for SQL identifiers is a MySQLism, standard SQL uses double quotes (`"NBRHD_NAME"`) for such purposes and SQL Server uses brackets (`[NBRHD_NAME]`).

---

I just noticed this in your JavaScript:

```
var url = "census/search?query=" + query;
```

That would suggest that `params[:query]` contains what you're looking for but your controller is looking at `params[:search]`. The result is that your SQL says `like '%%'`. So fix up your quoting and then look at the right thing in `params`:

```
@census = Census.where("`NBRHD_NAME` like ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")
```

Comment: I try using both options but rails still persists in returning all the results while using backticks and no ticks

Comment: What's in `params[:search]` and what `NBRHD_NAME` values does it match that you don't think it should?

Comment: That's the problem is it appears to not be matching the values at all and will just return all the results from the DB.

Comment: Again: What is in `params[:search]` when it matches everything? What `NBRHD_NAME` values is it matching that you don't think it should? Is `params[:search]` empty perhaps? Given that you're sending your query in as `?query`, I'd suspect that there's nothing in `params[:search]`...

Comment: What I am doing is sending an ajax request calling: 'census/search?query=_SearchString_'  and in my return response I am getting back all the results.  I do not know if my `params[:search]` is blank, that is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Never mind I was a total idiot.  I forgot that the hash `search` should have also been in the ajax url i was sending.  Thank you though for pointing out some other key facts.  I get this was what you were trying to point out to me.